# Required data frame after explode or other option to fill a running difference b/w two columns pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Input data frame as given given below,

```
 data = {
        'labels': ["A","B","A","B","A","B","M","B","M","B","M"],
        'start': [0,9,13,23,47,77,81,92,100,104,118],
        'stop': [9,13,23,47,77,81,92,100,104,118,145],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

   labels  start  stop
0       A      0     9
1       B      9    13
2       A     13    23
3       B     23    47
4       A     47    77
5       B     77    81
6       M     81    92
7       B     92   100
8       M    100   104
9       B    104   118
10      M    118   145
```

The output data frame required is as below,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['start'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(x['start'] + 1, x['stop'] + 1), axis=1)
df = df.explode('start')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   labels start  stop
0       A     1     9
0       A     2     9
0       A     3     9
0       A     4     9
0       A     5     9
0       A     6     9
0       A     7     9
0       A     8     9
0       A     9     9
1       B    10    13
1       B    11    13
1       B    12    13
1       B    13    13
2       A    14    23
2       A    15    23
2       A    16    23
2       A    17    23
2       A    18    23
2       A    19    23
2       A    20    23
2       A    21    23
2       A    22    23
2       A    23    23
...
```